# Detect when a JLabel (or similar) is dragged off a component

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlabel, jcomponent

How do I detect when something like a JLabel is dragged off a component? I am trying to create an effect like the OS X dock when removing applications from it.

I've tried using DragSourceContext's dragDropEnded() method to detect when a component has been dropped, but it has a delay because it seems to wait until the transfer is done processing.

Anyone deal with this before?

Answer (score 2):

May be this http://java-sl.com/dockable.html ?